# How to use register memory for each thread in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I am trying to flip upside down the array which size is big.(ex. 4096x8192)
At first, I tried with two array for input and output and It works!.
(I will say input is original and output is flipped array)

But I thought it will be easier and much efficient if each thread can hold input elements.
Then I can only use one array!

Could you guys share your knowledge or introduce any documents that help this problem?

Thanks and here is my code.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#define ThreadPB 32 // optimal size
dim3 threadsPerBlock(ThreadPB, ThreadPB);

__global__ void initKernel(int *input, int nx, int ny)
{
    int idx_x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int idx_y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int idx = idx_y * nx + idx_x;

    if (idx_x < nx && idx_y < ny) {
        input[idx] = idx_y;
    }

}


__global__ void flipKernel(int *output, int *input, int nx, int ny)
{
    int idx_x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int idx_y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int idx = idx_y * nx + idx_x;
    
    // is it possible to use only one array?
    if (idx_x < nx && idx_y < ny) { 
        output[(ny - idx_y - 1) * nx + idx_x] = input[idx_y * nx + idx_x];
    }
}

int main()
{
    // time check
    cudaEvent_t start, stop, start_temp, stop_temp;
    cudaEvent_t start_temp2, stop_temp2;
    float elapsedTime, elapsedTime_temp, elapsedTime_temp2;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);        cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventCreate(&start_temp);   cudaEventCreate(&stop_temp);
    cudaEventCreate(&start_temp2);  cudaEventCreate(&stop_temp2);

    const int num_x = 4096;
    const int num_y = 8192;
    const int arraySize = num_x * num_y;

    int *orig, *flip;
    orig = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * arraySize);
    flip = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * arraySize);

    int *dev_orig = 0;
    int *dev_flip = 0;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_orig, arraySize * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_flip, arraySize * sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_orig, orig, arraySize * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_flip, flip, arraySize * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);



    dim3 blocksFlip((num_x + threadsPerBlock.x - 1) / threadsPerBlock.x, (num_y + threadsPerBlock.y - 1) / threadsPerBlock.y);
    initKernel << <blocksFlip, threadsPerBlock >> > (dev_orig, num_x, num_y);
    
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    flipKernel << <blocksFlip, threadsPerBlock >> > (dev_flip, dev_orig, num_x, num_y);

    // time check end
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0); cudaEventSynchronize(stop); cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start, stop); printf("flip 1024x2048 처리 시간 = %f ms.\n", elapsedTime);


    cudaMemcpy(orig, dev_orig, arraySize * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(flip, dev_flip, arraySize * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // check flip works
    printf("FLIP this array { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6, 7, 8, 9...} \n= { %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d...}\n",
        flip[num_x * 0], flip[num_x * 1], flip[num_x * 2], flip[num_x * 3], flip[num_x * 4],
        flip[num_x * 5], flip[num_x * 6], flip[num_x * 7], flip[num_x * 8], flip[num_x * 9]);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an even number of rows in the array, you should be able to do something like this:

```
__global__ void flipKernel(int *input, int nx, int ny)
{
    int idx_x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int idx_y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    int idx = idx_y * nx + idx_x;
    
    if (idx_x < nx && idx_y < ny/2) { 
        int output_temp = input[(ny - idx_y - 1) * nx + idx_x];
        input[(ny - idx_y - 1) * nx + idx_x] = input[idx_y * nx + idx_x];
        input[idx_y * nx + idx_x] = output_temp;
    }
}
```

You would only need to launch this kernel with half as many threads in y (half as many rows in y).  Each thread is updating two values in the matrix.

Rather than thinking about things like "register" or imagining that CUDA is some kind of weird language, if you have C or C++ programming ability, I would encourage you to think about how you might solve the problem if it were framed as an ordinary C or C++ programming challenge.  Your intuition from that will often work very well in CUDA.

The core of the routine above is just a [swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/41621/).  The thing you are referring to as a "register" is just an ordinary local variable in C or C++. There is a `register` keyword in C++, but it serves essentially no purpose in CUDA, and is not needed here anyway.

You can handle an odd number of rows by simply leaving the middle row as-is, and swapping the remaining rows.  This would require just a slight change to the indexing calculations.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details. Here is another question.
Is 'output_temp' exist in each threads? Am I understand alright?

Comment: Yes, a local variable is thread-local.  Each CUDA thread has its own, independent copy (i.e. instantiation, version) of `output_temp`.

Comment: Ah I got it. Thank you again.